# Cursors in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way in BigQuery Scripting to declare cursor as we have in MySql Scripting.
I have to Schedule a script to run periodically, There is a logic where 
Step 1: Extract all enterprise names (Multiple rows output)
Step 2: For each enterprise, go to an enterprise's table and run some update queries.

MySql Has Cursor Which helps with this kind of functionality in scripting. I was referring to BigQuery's Scripting page, but could not find any such thing.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#set

Are there Cursor equivalent in BigQuery?

Is there any other way I can do, what I want to bo with whats available in BigQuery scripting?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a SQL cursor in BigQuery, but there are some alternatives that you can use instead, as a first option you could use a [temporary table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#temporary_tables), which will exist for the lifetime of the current script. Tables created within a procedure are still available when the procedure call returns, until the primary script finishes.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE light AS
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_lightning.lightning_2019` LIMIT 1000;

SELECT * FROM light;
```

Additionally there is the `WITH` statement ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with-clause)) to make a reference to a SELECT(s), with the restriction that you have to do the operations within the same clause, which may be for example the call of a User-Defined Function ([UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions)) or a stored procedure ([SP](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/command-and-control-now-easier-in-bigquery-with-scripting-and-stored-procedures)) for the required update operation(s).

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_lightning.lightning_2019` LIMIT 1000
)
SELECT * FROM data;
```

Finally you can use an [array](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#bigquery-scripting) to get all the enterprise names, and later within a loop do the required update operations (also you could call a UDF or a SP).

```
-- Sample from the official documentation for the use of an array
-- Declare a variable to hold names as an array.
DECLARE top_names ARRAY<STRING>;
-- Build an array of the top 100 names from the year 2017.
SET top_names = (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(name ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 100)
  FROM `bigquery-public-data`.usa_names.usa_1910_current
  WHERE year = 2017
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following simulate looping through a cursor in BigQuery

BEGIN

```
DECLARE x INT64 DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE z INT64 DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_country AS
SELECT country, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY country) rownum
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT country
FROM `bigquery-public-data.faa.us_airports`)
order by country;

SET z= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_country);

WHILE x<=z DO

  SELECT country 
  FROM temp_country
  WHERE rownum = x;

SET x=x+1;

END WHILE;
```

END;

Answer (score 1):

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#for-in

```
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE t_name STRING;
    
    FOR GOIABA IN (  
        SELECT TABLE_ID
        FROM `MyDataSet`.`__TABLES__`)
    
      DO 
        BEGIN
            SET t_name = GOIABA.TABLE_ID;
        END;
    END FOR;
    END;
```