# How do you handle large query results for a simple select in bigquery with the python client library?

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table where I wrote 1.6 million records, and each has two columns: an ID, and a JSON string column.

I want to select all of those records and write the json in each row as a file. However, the query result is too large, and I get the 403 associated with that:
"403 Response too large to return. Consider specifying a destination table in your job configuration."

I've been looking at the below documentation around this and understand that they recommend specifying a table for the results and viewing them there, BUT all I want to do is `select *` from the table, so that would effectively just be copying it over, and I feel like I would run into the same issue querying that result table.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/introduction
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationQuery.FIELDS.allow_large_results

What is the best practice here? Pagination? Table sampling? `list_rows`?

I'm using the python client library as stated in the question title. My current code is just this:

```
query = f'SELECT * FROM `{project}.{dataset}.{table}`'
return client.query(query)
```

I should also mention that the IDs are not sequential, they're just alphanumerics.

Comment: Try looking for some cursor functionality? [Maybe this question will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937084/cursors-in-bigquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice and efficient way is to [export your data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data?hl=en) and then download it instead of querying the whole table (`SELECT *`).

From there, you may extract your needed data from the exported files (eg. CSV, JSON, etc) using python code without having to wait for your code to finish the `SELECT *` query.